# Was Daitya king Bali present during the Samudra Manthan? If so then how was it possible? Please check the details

Tags: avatars, bali

I have no quotes but recently many misconceptions and questions have arised in my mind by watching two Tv serials. Devon Ke Dev Mahadev (2012) and Sankat mochan mahabali hanuman (2016). Both of them depict Bali as being present during the Samudra Manthan. now the reason i am asking this question is because of the chronology the timeline seems to not make any sense. How can Vali be present during the 2nd Avatar of Vishnu (Kurma during Samudra Manthan) when he himself is the grandson of Prahlada?

1. Samudra Manthan, second avatar of Vishnu, Bali is present and talks to Mohini
2. Birth of Hiranyaksha (great grand-uncle of Bali)
3. Birth of Hiranyakasipu (great grandfather of Bali)
4. Hiranyaksha adopts Andhaka
5. Varaha (3rd AVATAR OF VISNU) kills Hiranyaksha
6. Hiranyakasipu (great-grandfather of Bali) performs penance to Brahma and wins boons
7. Prahlada (grandfather of Bali) is born
8. Narasimha (4th avatar of Visnu) kills Hiranyakasipu
9. Birochan (father of Bali and son of Prahlada) is born
10. Bali is present during the 5th avatar of Vishnu (Vamana) and loses all of his land.

Does it make any sense? Can someone tell me the truth?

Comment: Nog Shine i know you edited the question and put Bali instead of Vali. But i would like you to know that he was called Vali in Mahabharata not Bali. So it's a valid name.

Comment: That's a regional difference. Vali is sanskrit name an dit is used in Scriptures.  Vali (वालि ) means brother of Sugriva a Vanara.  Bali is the son of Virochan and grand son of prahlada. Sanskrit names are authentic and I wasn't one who edited BTW.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Bali was there during the churning of the ocean. He led the rakshasas during the churning. He took the Uccaiḥśravā, the white horse generated from  the milky ocean.

> tata uccaiḥśravā nāma hayo ’bhūc candra-pāṇḍuraḥ |
>   tasmin baliḥ spṛhāṁ cakre nendra īśvara-śikṣayā  ||
>
> Thereafter, a horse named Uccaiḥśravā, which was as white as the moon, was generated. Bali Mahārāja desired to possess this horse, and Indra, the King of heaven, did not protest, for he had previously been so advised by the Supreme Personality of Godhead. [[Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam 8.8.3]](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/8/3)

It makes sense because the Kurma avatara was not the second incarnation of Vishnu. The famous order of the Vishnu's ten incarnations famously known as Dashavatar which is publicised is as follows:

Matsya, Kurma, Varaha, Narasimha, Vamana, Parashu Rama, Bala Rama [in some versions, he is placed with Buddha], Krishna, Buddha, Kalki.

But, on the contrary, the order is not right. Also there are infinite incarnations of Lord Vishnu. We don't know all the incarnations. This is what Krishna Paramatma says in Bhagavad Gita.

> bahūni me vyatītāni janmāni tava cārjuna |
>   tānyahaṃ veda sarvāṇi na tvaṃ vettha parantapa || 5 ||
>
> Many, many births both you and I have passed. I can remember all of them, but you cannot, O subduer of the enemy.

Similarly, in the Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam, Canto 1 chapter 3.

> अवतारा हि असङ्ख्येया हरेः सत्त्व-निधेर् द्विजाः
>     यथाविदासिनः कुल्याः सरसः स्युः सहस्रशः
>
> avatārā hi asaṅkhyeyā hareḥ sattva-nidher dvijāḥ
>     yathāvidāsinaḥ kulyāḥ sarasaḥ syuḥ sahasraśaḥ
>
> O brāhmaṇas, the incarnations of the Lord are innumerable, like rivulets flowing from inexhaustible sources of water.

There are [24 important incarnations](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19959/5212) mentioned in the Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam. Garuda Purana mentions other incarnations besides these.

Now, the chronological order of Dashavatara is mentioned in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21996/5212) answer by [TheDestroyer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/3500/the-destroyer) where manvantaras are also described.

The chronological order of the incarnations(in present Sweta Varaha Kalpa) mentioned in the question are:

- Varaha  - At beginning of Varaha Kalpa to rescue the earth and also to slay Hiranyaksha.
- Narasimha - Tamasa Manvantara i.e., fourth manvantara.
- Kurma  - Chakshusha Manvantara i.e., sixth manvantara
- Mohini -  Chakshusha Manvantara i.e., sixth manvantara
- Vamana -  Vaivasvata Manvantara i.e., seventh manvantara.

I think it makes sense now.

Comment: thanks but i think other people would be able to come up with a counterargument like saying he has only had 9 avatars not 24.

Comment: I don't understand. Why would people come up with the argument there are only nine? I gave the reference for it too. It is from Bhagavatam. That argument fails. The nine or ten are only famous ones. There are many other incarnations we don't know. The incarnations like Narayana,  Hayagriva, Swan, Mohini are not among the dashavataras.

Comment: So before samudra manthan (churning of the ocean) did the Devas NOT have amrita (nectar/immortality)?

Comment: they would do it cause they trust TV series that call Rama the 7th avatar and say visnu only had 10 avatars and cause they dont believe in bhagavatam.

Comment: There were all the riches and treasures. They were lost due to a curse of Durvasa to Indra. See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20823/5212) answer We can sue [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) for further discussion if you want to discuss further about it. :)

Comment: Also adding to the list
Matsya-avatar - rescued vaivasvat manu while entering 7th manvantara.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion is justified. But these are two different people. I am referring from Guru Bannanje Govindacharya's bhagavatha pravachana.

Bali of Raivatha manvanthara was present during Samudra mathana.(manthan)

Bali of Vaivasvatha manvanthara was present during Vamana avatar.

It is also believed that Prahlada will take birth in each manvanthara. So both Bali (grandson of Prahlada) and Prahlada (Not as son Hiranya kashyapu) will be present in each manvanthara.

Answer (score 0):

It is said that Bali who was grandson of Prahlada was present during Samudra Manthana.  To make sense of this somewhat misplaced chronology we must understand that Samudra Manthana happened twice. Once during Raivata manvantara and vaivasvata manvantara, hence Kurma avatara happened twice. Furthermore, to understand the conundrum of Bali being present we must know that Prahlada and his lineage were present in every manvantara. Hence the Bali mentioned in Samudra Manthana can be attributed to as the one which had taken place during Raivata manvantara. Also, Bali is the name of a Jeeva present during Samudra Manthana. It is not mentioned there that he is the grandson of Prahlada. That Jeeva might have reincarnated in Prahalad’s lineage.
source : Bannanje Govindacharya's Harikathaamruthasara pravachana

Comment: Welcome to HSE! You could have a look at the help centre on how to answer questions as well as the meta post on [Guidelines for new users answering](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). We insist on citing sources from scriptures and quoting them in answers.